# What is the default.conf setting for hosting SPAs created with React on Nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I would like to host a SPA created with React on Nginx.
In doing so, I would like to configure the path settings to route to the React SPA when a path starting with "/login/" is accessed, such as "/login/foo", "/login/bar", etc.
I have currently configured the following, but it does not work.

default.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /login/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir /var/www \
mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/login \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install vim less -y
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/login　# ReactSPA index.html is placed in "/usr/share/nginx/html/login" of Nginx container
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Setting the ReactSPA path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ReactNotifications />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login/common" element={<CommonLogin />} />
          <Route path="/login/fuga" element={<FugaLogin />} />
          <Route path="/login/piyo" element={<PiyoLogin />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

After the above configuration, I start the Nginx container and access to "http://localhost:8080/login/common", and get "Page unreachable" as shown in the following picture, and the port number in the address bar is gone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW9oB.png)

Looking at the network section in the developer tools, it appears that no response is being returned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YIwX.png)

How can I configure it to access ReactSPA when accessing a path beginning with "/login/"?

Already mentioned in the issue details.